# Something like a field but with 3 operations?

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know of Groups, and Rings, and Fields but what about tacking on a 3rd operation. Is there any use in considering some structure that consists of a field but with a 3rd operation (possibly less well behaved than the other two)?

The link in the comments is helpful, but to make this question more specific I would be interested in something that is a field under the first two operations.

Comment: A very relevant post: [Why don't we study algebraic objects with more than two operations?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/351369/why-dont-we-study-algebraic-objects-with-more-than-two-operations)

Comment: Ahh! Thank you for that link, to make the question a bit more precise I would be interested in something that requires the set to be a field under the first two operations.

Comment: @Twiltie: Universal Algebra might interest you :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have a look through [*A Course in Universal Algebra*](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.math.hawaii.edu/~ralph/Classes/619/univ-algebra.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjhuNHKjZ_kAhVOVBUIHVqFAikQFjAAegQIBBAB&usg=AOvVaw1muUkYCcqfsfYQdkE6ELBE), by S. Burris & H.P. Sankappanavar. You'll find many examples of algebras with more than two operations there. It builds up a rich theory for them in fact, proving, for instance, the isomorphism theorems in full generality.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the link is exactly what I was looking for and very interesting, I'll have to read it!

Comment: @Twiltie: You're welcome :)

Comment: Thank you, @Ilmari Karonen :)

Comment: No problem. FWIW, I've asked a mod to look into how that spam edit managed to get approved in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

[Poisson algebras](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_algebra) come to mind.  They have an associative ring structure as well as a second "multiplication" that behaves as a Lie bracket, compatible with the first multiplication.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That is close to what I am looking for but the operations seem a little more restricted than just some arbitrary field with an operation tacked on. If nothing else comes up in a couple of hours I will accept!