# How many associative ternary operations there are on a finite set?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups, binary-operations

We know that algebraic operation is a function  $f:\underbrace{\left ( X\times X\times \cdots \times X\right )}_{t\ \text{times}}\rightarrow{X}$

If $X$ is a set and and cardinality is $|X|=n$ then there are $n^{(n^t)}$ functions or       't'-nary algebraic operations on that set.
If $t=2$ then the operation is called a "binary operation" and there are $n^{(n^2)}$ operations.
If cardinality of $|X|=2$ then we will have $2^{(2^2)}=16$ binary operations.
Those operations are:
$$1) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  a&  a&  \\ 
 &  a&  a&
\end{array} 
2) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  a&  a&  \\ 
 &  a&  b&
\end{array} 
3) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  a&  a&  \\ 
 &  b&  a&
\end{array} 
4) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  a&  b&  \\ 
 &  a&  a&
\end{array}
5) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  b&  a&  \\ 
 &  a&  a&
\end{array} $$ 
$$6) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  a&  a&  \\ 
 &  b&  b&
\end{array} 
7) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  a&  b&  \\ 
 &  a&  b&
\end{array} 
8) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  b&  a&  \\ 
 &  a&  b&
\end{array} 
9)                         
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  a&  b&  \\ 
 &  b&  a&
\end{array} 
10) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  b&  a&  \\ 
 &  b&  a&
\end{array} 
11) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  b&  b&  \\ 
 &  a&  a&
\end{array} $$
$$12) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  a&  b&  \\ 
 &  b&  b&
\end{array} 
13) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  b&  a&  \\ 
 &  b&  b&
\end{array} 
14) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  b&  b&  \\ 
 &  a&  b&
\end{array} 
15) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  b&  b&  \\ 
 &  b&  a&
\end{array} 
16) 
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
* &  &    \\ \hline
 &  b&  b&  \\ 
 &  b&  b&
\end{array}
$$
$$a,b \in \mathbb X$$
Only 8 operations from this list are associative. Right! 
Those are $1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12, 16$
Because they satisfy associativity condition: $(a*b)*c=a*(b*c)$ where $a,b,c \in \mathbb X$.
Things will get more difficult if $n=3$ or $|X|=3$, we will have 113 associative operations.

But what if $t=3$?
$$f:X\times X\times X \rightarrow{X}$$
Then the operation is called a "ternary operation" and there are $n^{(n^3)}$ operations. Right!
My question is How many ternary operations from that are associative?
Even when cardinality is $|X|=2$, How many associative operations might be from $2^{(2^3)}=2^8=256$ operations?
And finally: Is there a formula about computing ternary operations on a finite set with $|X|=n$ cardinality?

Comment: What does it mean for a ternary operator to be associative?

Comment: I dont know! Maybe here is an answer?  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/94690/is-anybody-researching-ternary-groups

Comment: so you are asking us to count objects, but don't have a definition?

Comment: I have already asked this question here! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/517502/does-ternary-operations-have-associative-property

Comment: $$f(a,b,f(c,d,e))=f(f(a,b,c),d,e)=f(a,f(b,c,d),e)$$   or $$a*b*(c*d*e)=a*(b*c*d)*e=(a*b*c)*d*e$$

Comment: Hot tip, solve the $n=2$ case before moving on to the $n=3$ case.

Comment: Certainly, it is an "unnatural" extension of associativity. This is because any associative binary operation on $X$ can be represented as a subset of some algebra $(Y^Y,\circ)$, the algebra of functions from $Y$ to $Y$ with binary operator being function composition. That is, function composition is, in some sense, the most basic binary associative operator, and i tis why we care about associativity of binary operators.

Comment: @IremadzeArchil19910311 May I ask how you count the associative binary operations for $n = 3$?

Comment: here is an answer for your question! http://www.math.umt.edu/tmme/vol5no2and3/TMME_vol5nos2and3_a8_pp.257_268.pdf

Comment: Why the shouting?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @IremadzeArchil19910311: associativity could maybe be extended by studying prefix- or postfix-patterns?