# What's the automorphism group of $ax-b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}: a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$ on $\Bbb Q_2$?

Tags: group-theory, p-adic-number-theory, automorphism-group

Let $f_{a,b}(x)=ax-b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}$ act on the 2-adic numbers.

Then I have as a fairly resolute theorem that for any choice of two 2-adic units $a,b$, every $f_{a,b}$ is topologically conjugate to the others.  I.e. there is a homeomorphism $T$ that topologically conjugates any given $f_{a,b}(x)$ to another.

To give a little insight into the function, it commutes with $2x$ in the sense that $f(2x)=f(x)$ or in other words it acts faithfully on the obvious quotient $\Bbb Q_2\to\Bbb Z_2^\times$ and therefore its action on the quotient $\Bbb Q_2/{\langle2\rangle}$ is sufficient to define it.

It follows that these functions generate a subgroup of the automorphism group of $\Bbb Q_2/\langle2\rangle$.  If we let $T_{1,1}(x)$ be the identity homeomorphism which conjugates $f_{a,b}$ to $f_{a,b}$ then each homeomorphism is written:

$T_{a,b}(x)=\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty2^{\nu_2(f_{a,b}^n(x))}$

Where $n$ indicates compositions of $f$.

I'd like to understand the group these generate.

Elements of the form $T_{1,b}$ are straightforward because $T_{1,b}=b\times T_{1,1}$ and therefore the inverse is $T_{1.\frac1b}$.  Which is helpful because this category of operations is therefore also commutative and closed to $b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$.

But inverses of $T_{a,1}$ and $T_{a,b}$ I'm not so sure about, nor commutativity and closure of say $T_{a_1,1}\circ T_{a_2,1}$.

**Question**

What's the automorphism group of $ax-b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}: a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$ on $\Bbb Q_2$?  In particular, do the generators $T_{a,b}:a,b\in\Bbb Z_2^\times$ generate elements beyond themselves and if so, what is the set and the operation?

**Edit**

I attempted an answer based upon composing two affine transformations $ax+b$ and $cx+d$ but I was able to confirm this fails:

If $T_{a,b}$ topologically conjugates $f_{a,b}(x)=ax-b\cdot2^{\nu_2(x)}$ to $f_{1,1}(x)=x-2^{\nu_2(x)}$ then for composition do we we have:

$T_{a,b}\circ T_{c,d}=T_{ca,cb+d}$
?

This would generate the group having the set $T_{a,b}:a\in\Bbb Z_2^\times, b\in\Bbb Z_2$

Note that $T_{1,1}(x)$ is the identity function because it sends the standard binary representation of any 2-adic number to itself.

And NO, this doesn't work because it fails to agree with $f_{1,b}\circ f_{1,d}=f_{1,b\times d}$

Curiously, this attempt yields addition of $b,d$ instead of multiplication.

Comment: apologies to anyvody reading this I previously exchanged $a,b$ in error which is now fixed.

Comment: One of the first things I don't understand is whether you are interested in the group generated by the $f_{a,b}$, or by what you call the $T_{a,b}$. --- I also have to guess what $T_{a,b}$ is supposed to be in the first place: Is it the supposed to be "the" homeomorphism conjugating $f_{a,b}$ to $f_{1,1}$? And is the $f$ in its sum formula short for $f_{a,b}$? Because whatever supposedly conjugates $f_{a,b}$ to $f_{a',b'}$ would presumably depend on four parameters $a,b,a',b'$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes, I'm interested in the group generated by all the $T$.  These $T$ are the functions which conjugate the $f$ to each other.  But I don't see why you have to guess what $T_{a,b}(x):\Bbb Q_2\to\Bbb Q_2$ is because I have written it explicitly. I have just added a subscript $a,b$ which may have been the ambiguity you are referring to, but if any remains, please elucidate.  EDIT: I just saw you mentioned the lack of the subscripts, apologies I thought that was obvious and the text was so tiny I originally thought the subscript detracted, but maybe that was a misjudgement.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg apologies, in case this also is not obvious $T_{1,1}(x)$ is the identity function on $\Bbb Q_2\to\Bbb Q_2$ and $T_{a,b}$ is the function which sends identity to $T_{a,b}$.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I've crossposted here and this time I have gone slowly and hopefully with great clarity and precision (at the expense of conciseness): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455325/

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I posted my attempt at an answer. Not sure if it's right. I dunno if you can help?

Comment: Sorry @TorstenSchoeneberg I attempted and answer but I was able to confirm it is wrong so I added to the question so please ignore my previous comment.